# How to change background colour of Main Camera in runtime setting RGBA values?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, background-color

Here is my code to access and change background colour of Main Camera

```
Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = new Color(228f,234f,241f,0f);
```

This code makes the background white and set values very much higher in inspector. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a skybox?

Comment: And where do you put this code? What do you attach the script to?

Comment: @FarhanAnam No, There isn't any skyBox.
Code is in a function which is perfectly executing. Posting complete script will create confusion and will require lots of explanation. Isn't it clear from this?

Comment: read this : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-backgroundColor.html

Comment: and this : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html

Comment: I still don't understand how do I set values as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colour values are normalised, i.e they range from 0 to 1 ([see the documentation here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html)). So, divide each value you have there by 255 to get the actual value.

EDIT: as suggested by @FarhanAnam, here's how you would do that.

```
Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = new Color(228f / 255f, 234f / 255f, 241f  / 255f, 0f);
```

Comment: How do I divide? I mean I divide which number to to which to get expected result? Values I am passing here is taken from inspector.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I tried this
        
Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = new Color((228/255),(234/255),(241/255),(0/255));

But it becomes black now

Answer (score 3):

Color structure takes floats as arguments so you need to convert color to 0.0 - 1.0.

e.g

```
Camera.main.backgroundColor = new Color(0f, 1f, 0f);
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand how do I convert?

Comment: Ok, let me explain. The value of RGB can be 0 - 255 or 0.0 - 1.0 so if you want to change e.g. R= 230, G=182, B=11. You have to divide each one by 255 to get value that is between 0 and 1.

Comment: I tried this
        
    Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = new Color((228/255),(234/255),(241/255),(0/255));

And it becomes black.

Comment: It worked. I can mark only one answer to be correct, unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

No need to divide - just use a unity built in [`Color32`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html):

```
Camera.main.GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = new Color32(228,234,241,0);
```

Note that the `Color32` constructor requires `byte` type operands and not floats.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as well. Can you tell me which one will be more efficient to use?

Comment: Probably mine - at least in 32 bit screen color mode. But if you don't change the color a few hundred times per frame, it won't matter.